# Magento and BST Timezone issue

Tags: php, magento, datetime, timezone

I running a Magento store in CentOS on top of a LEMP stack and I am trying to import orders from the website into our CRM using `created_at` date time of the order (so we can carry out delta updates).

The server's timezone is **Europe/London** and my php-fpm pool config (for my site) is said to be the same also:

```
php_admin_value[date.timezone] = Europe/London
```

I created an order and it correctly shows when the order was created at, for example:

[image]

However, if I looked at this order in the database, the `created_at` is set to one hour earlier (leads me to believe the BST timezone setting isn't in effect):

[image]

Does this mean Magento doesn't support BST? or is our magento setup incorrectly? or do I need a workaround (i.e. detect if daylight saving is on, then add/remove hour etc...)?

---

**Update**

This is how I have implemented `give me all the orders since my last sync` functionality, where `$API_Data` in the code below refers to last sync from server:

```
private function GetNewOrderIncrementIds($API_Data = '')
{
    // Init
    $now = new DateTime();

    // Set Timezone to Europe/London (From Config)
    $now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone(Mage::getStoreConfig('mymodule_config/system_config/default_timezone')));

    // Generate Date & Time
    $fromDate = $API_Data;
    $toDate   = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    // Load Straight Order Sync Config
    $sos_enabled  = ((int)Mage::getStoreConfig('mymodule_config/order_sync/straight_order_sync_enabled'));
    $sos_storeid  = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('mymodule_config/order_sync/straight_order_sync_storeid');
    $sos_shipping = Mage::getStoreConfig('mymodule_config/order_sync/straight_order_sync_shippingmethod');

    // Load Order Collection
    $order_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
            'from' => $fromDate,
            'to' => $toDate
        ));

    // Build Order Increment Id List
    $new_orders = array();
    foreach ($order_collection as $order)
    {
        // Check If This Order Is Straight Order Sync
        $doSOS = ($sos_enabled &&
                  (int)$order->getStoreId() == $sos_storeid &&
                  $order->getShippingMethod() == $sos_shipping);

        // Append Order
        $new_orders[] = array(
            'OrderNumber' => $order->getIncrementId(),
            'DoSOS'       => $doSOS
        );
    }
    $order_collection = null;

    // Finished
    $this->API_Response(false, '', json_encode(array(
        'LastSync'  => $toDate,
        'NewOrders' => $new_orders
    )));
}
```

Comment: I'd say it's working perfectly.  BST is UTC+1, so 16:19:31 BST is 15:19:31 UTC.  It's good that the DB values are in UTC.  Otherwise, a value [during the fall-back transition](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london) would be ambiguous.

Comment: I've updated my question showing my code. I need this to work via my code, so I never miss an order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento sets script’s time relative to server time, converted to UTC. So each Magento store (database-wise) is synced to UTC. Read more @ [Guide through Magento’s timezones](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/guide-through-magentos-timezones/)

To save created_at date use

> Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate()

To retrieve created_at store date use

> Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), $format, true);
>
> see /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php

To get order date

```
foreach ($order_collection as $order)
    {
       ...
       $created_at = Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($order->getCreatedAt(), 'medium', true);
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. I've updated my question with code showing how I am trying to use the `created_at` to load orders from last sync (delta updates). How or where can I use this `getCreatedAtStoreDate` so that I will always work with the correct date & time to keep the my orders in sync?

Comment: Assuming that you want to export the local time that the order was created then `$created_at = Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($order->getCreatedAt(), 'medium', true);`